# Installing apk repeatedly on glass

Tags: android, google-glass

Is it bad to keep running the sequence of commands, via adb
via the command line, during Google Glass development:

```
adb shell pm clear    (to kill the application)
adb uninstall
adb install
adb shell am start
adb shell am start
adb shell am start
adb shell am start    (I keep having to do this because
                       the display keeps going black)
```

over and over?

Is there flash memory that would get ruined eventually, or
a heating issue?  I would be running this cycle 100-200
times a day, quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only re-installing your own APK, you should use this instead:

```
adb install -r <PATH/TO/APP.APK>
```

This will take care of killing your running Glassware and re-installing it, as long as it has the same signing certificate. You can then use `adb` to start your Activity through the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you're trying to avoid the screen to turn black by spamming the ActivityManager.

Ways to fix this are:

- Turn off the screen dimming in the developer options
- Use the immersive attribute in your AndroidManifest.xml for the Acitvity

  `android:immersive="true"`
- Request the WindowManager to keep the screen on. (In your Activity)

  `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`
- Request the WindowManager to keep the screen on. (In your layout)

  `android:keepScreenOn="true"`